# Is it true that $Fr(A\cup B)=Fr(A)\cup Fr(B)$ if $A\cap\overline{B}=\emptyset$ and $\overline{A}\cap B=\emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A,B\subseteq X$. Is it true that $Fr(A\cup B)=Fr(A)\cup Fr(B)$ if $A\cap\overline{B}=\emptyset$ and $\overline{A}\cap B=\emptyset$?

I think it is true. Here I'm using that $Fr(Y)=\overline{Y}\setminus Int(Y)$.

If $x\in Fr(A\cup B)=(\overline{A}\cup\overline{B})\setminus Int(A\cup B)$, then $x\in \overline{A}\setminus Int(A)$ or $x\in\overline{B}\setminus Int(B)$, so $x\in Fr(A)\cup Fr(B)$. So it's always $Fr(A\cup B)\subseteq Fr(A)\cup Fr(B)$.

But I don't see how to show $Fr(A)\cup Fr(B)\subseteq Fr(A\cup B)$ by using $A\cap\overline{B}=\emptyset$ and $\overline{A}\cap B=\emptyset$.

Would you give me any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Take a point $x\in Fr(A)$ and an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$.  You want to show that $U$ is not contained in $A\cup B$, to show that $x$ is not in the interior of $A\cup B$.  To show this, consider separately the cases where $x\in\overline{B}$ and $x\not\in\overline{B}$.  In the first case, show $x\not\in A\cup B$, and in the second case think about the set $V=U\setminus \overline{B}$ and use the fact that $x$ is not in the interior of $A$.

Comment: Do you mean $V$ is an open neighborhood of $x$? I see that $V$ is open, but why $x\in X\setminus\overline{B}$? As $A\cap\overline{B}=\emptyset$ it would be suffice that $x\in A$, but we only know $x\in\overline{A}$.

Comment: You're right, the argument is more complicated than I thought at first.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I see. If $x\in\overline{B}$ then $x\notin A$. And $x\notin B$ because $x\in\overline{A}$, so clearly $U$ is not contained in $A\cup B$. In the second case $V$ is not contained in $A$, and every $z\in V\cap (X\setminus A)$ is a point such that $z\in U$ but $z\notin A\cup B$. Thank you.